# Is there a program that will emulate typewriter sounds?

Tags: software-recommendation, keyboard

Since I switched to Ubuntu 12.04 I'd only missed one thing.

A program which could launch typewriter sounds while typing. For instance, in Windows I used this: http://www.colorpilot.com/soundpilot.html for a long time.

I learned then that this writing program: http://gottcode.org/focuswriter/ had the sounds but only for the program itself.

However, sometimes I'm writing an email, writing on the web or doing more complex writing tasks in LibreOffice - all places where these long missed typing sounds don't apply.

Does any of you know of any plans in the community of the sound bit - typing sounds - as an independent program or applet to be fetched in the Ubuntu Software Center soon?

Comment: I just changed the instructions to make them a bit easier to follow. Try them again!

Comment: The keypress script was using 78% of my CPU. When I stopped running it the CPU usage went to 12%.
Even if it's fun, it's not worth that.

Comment: Another suggestion saving resources and make it more real: Purchase a keyboard with hard ticking buttons. It may be like those of Mac computers.

Answer (score 9):

There are some implementations to play a sound for every keypress, one of them is "[keypress](https://github.com/chrelad/keypress)" on Github.com, made by Github user "[chrelad](https://github.com/chrelad)". It's a fork of [linux-typewriter](https://github.com/colszowka/linux-typewriter).

Instructions on how to set it up:

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Install the package [python-xlib](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/python-xlib).

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-xlib
   ```
3. Download the application:

   ```
   wget -O keypress.tar.gz https://github.com/chrelad/keypress/tarball/master
   tar xvfz keypress.tar.gz && cd chrelad*
   ```
4. Start it by executing

   ```
   ./keypress.py
   ```
5. Optional: You can change the sound by opening the file *keypress.py* with an editor and look out for the line that says

   ```
           os.system("aplay sounds/key01.wav")
   ```

Now change key01.wav to what you want it to sound like.

---

To restart it after the reboot:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Type: `cd chrelad* && ./keypress.py`

Comment: If `./keypress.py` gives any error, try with `python2.7 ./keypress.py`

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used IncrediMail? You probably like its old but lovely typewriter sound effects when writing. But this sound effects can’t appear in Gmail or other text editing tools. Tiper, to eliminate this regret for you.

Copyright: appnee.com/tiper/#ixzz2GVXpQR7s
Under Creative Commons License: Attribution Non-Commercial No Derivatives

Comment: BTW, you need wine to run it!

Comment: So...what is Tiper, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: https://github.com/aitjcize/Qwertickle
This is exactly what you want.

Comment: please provide the essential info needed for installation andnuse of this app.