# Attempting to get my terminal to play a specific ogg file while I type

Tags: command-line, sound

My end game is to get my computer to make all of the sounds from my all time favorite video game from the 90's. I've already found the ogg file but now I want it to play every single time I type ANYTHING in the terminal.

For example: "fjeocjrigfjrig" would play the specified sound 14 times as I type. The clip for this is only about .3 seconds long. Is this possible?

I'd only like for this to happen while in the terminal. My google-fu turned up with nada.

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/197266/is-there-a-program-that-will-emulate-typewriter-sounds