# Mouse click beep

Tags: sound, mouse

Is there any way to get Ubuntu to beep whenever I press a mouse button.
I want to do this because many times I 'feel' the mouse button clicking, but it doesn't seem to register.

Comment: The [analogous question about the keyboard](http://askubuntu.com/q/197266/) might have some useful information.

Comment: Not a very helpful answer here: http://lockergnome.net/questions/158565/how-to-add-a-mouse-click-sound-in-linux suggesting using a mouse with a "mechanical spring".