# How to get audible feedback ("Thunk" sound, no typewriter) when pressing a keyboard key?

Tags: sound, keyboard

When I type I watch the keyboard rather than the screen. I need the noise that lets me know if my keystroke has  connected and produced a symbol.

With the typewriter, I frequently lean/press on some keys and produces a machine-gun clatter instead of a single key click.

I'm looking for "one-key-press (regardless of how hard or long) that produces a single click or THUNK.

Comment: Related question :  [Is there a program that will emulate typewriter sounds?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/197266/is-there-a-program-that-will-emulate-typewriter-sounds)

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 17.04 (or newer, I suppose) one can install with `sudo apt-get install bucklespring`, which will do what I think you want. Once installed, it can be started by simply executing `buckle` and stopped by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

If you're on an older Ubuntu, you can try to install bucklespring from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~mirabilos/+archive/ubuntu/ppa .

If the default sound recordings of IBM Model M are not suitable, you can replace them with your own. You can have a different sound for each key, but assuming you have only one sound, you need to make a few links to it, so that bucklespring will use it correctly. Assuming your sound file is called `sound.wav`:

```
cp -av /usr/share/buckle/wav my-sounds
cd my-sounds
for fname in ??-?.wav ; do ln -sfv ../sound.wav "${fname}" ; done
cd ..
buckle -p my-sounds
```

(If the delay between the keypress and the sound is too long for your needs, bucklespring seems to support jack, which supposedly introduces less latencies.)

Comment: If you are able to upgrade to 18.04 LTS, `bucklespring` is available from the standard repository.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck! After a simple google search I found a such app. 
If http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/keyboard-sounds-linux-when-typing doesn't work for you the search term you should use on google is `linux sound when i hit a key`

Comment: No luck.  I tried tickeys and even wrote the autor.  Like the suggestion above, i watch the keyboard rather than the screen.  I finallly found a typewriter emulator.  Better than nothing, but not the  loud THUNK that i would prefer.  I was 9/11'd out of a job where they used Sun computers.  Sun had a "click" command, but no src ..  ---Anybody else?